# If every proper subset of an infinite set $A$ is countable, then is the set $A$ also countable?

Tags: real-analysis

If every proper subset of an infinite set $A$ is countable, then is the set $A$ also countable?

**Attempt:** Suppose every proper subset of $A$ is countable. Then since $A$ is the union of the proper subsets of $A$. But, the power subset of infinite countable $A$ is uncountable, therefore, $A$ must be uncountable.

> But, a possible error here could be that many proper subsets may have a non-empty intersection. Thus, we may have **overcounted** many elements many times. Does that impact the uncountability of $A$? I am a bit confused

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I don’t think the intersection approach is the way to go.  Hint: the union of a countable set with a singleton outside that set is still countable.

Comment: @Paul Got it. I erred in my approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick some $x \in A$, and consider $A\setminus \{x\}$.  This is a proper subset of $A$, and therefore countable. Now consider $A\setminus \{x\} \cup \{x\}$, which is countable as it's the union with a singleton.  But this is the same as $A$, so $A$ is countable.

Comment: Thank you. $~~~$